# Is it possible to use gofmt on templates that are designed to be used with go generate?

Tags: go

I am using go:generate to handle automatically generating some database models and I was hoping to run my go template through `gofmt`, but it chokes with all the extra `{{ ... }}` dynamic sections.

Am I missing something obvious? I was hoping that this was a use case the `gofmt` people had addressed, given both `gofmt` and `go generate` are prominent parts of the go toolchain.

Obviously, it works to just run `go fmt` after `go generate` but it just feels dirty to have poorly formatted templates that are 99% go code sitting around.

Comment: gofmt needs to parse its input, so the input must use Go syntax. If 99% of your code are templates that are not valid Go, you might consider creating your own templatefmt tool.

Comment: It's not that 99% of my code are templates, it's 99% of each template is regular go code (only 1% are dynamic pieces that are evaluated during template rendering). Only a tiny fraction of my overall code base is templates.

Comment: sorry, I miss-understood. Still this will require a separate tool.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most generation tools execute the template to a *bytes.Buffer, format the buffer bytes using [format.Source](https://godoc.org/go/format#Source) and write the result to the output file.

Given template `t` and output writer `w`, the code looks something like this:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
if err := t.Execute(&buf, data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
p, err := format.Source(buf.Bytes())
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
w.Write(p)
```

Gofmting the template does not ensure that the output will be gofmted. Given how easy it is to gofmt the output using the go/format package, there's little value in creating a tool to gofmt templates.

Comment: That is very helpful to know how to do this programmatically (and so I've voted you up), but it doesn't answer my question, which appears may not have a good answer, unfortunately. What is the SO etiquette for this? Leave the question without an accepted answer in case a solution comes along?

Comment: @KevinBullaughey The question assumes a solution to the underlying problem: how does one produce gofmt'ed output from go generate?  One work around for accepting this answer is to edit the question to ask about the underlying problem. Because gofmt'ing the template does not ensure that the output will be gofmt'ed, it's not worth the effort to gofmt templates.

Comment: Actually, I think you did answer the question. I didn't think about it carefully enough. The short answer is 'no' and the reason is a bit subtle: (1) as you point out it's unnecessary because one can easily ensure the output is always properly formatted, and (2) even if one wanted to build such a tool, it would be impossible to parse the template based on the go language grammar because the template might be missing critical symbols, keywords, etc. and so even the concept of a properly formatted template is ill-defined. Thanks!