# Golang template range newline removal

Tags: templates, go

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the new lines in my template that are put there by the {{range}} and {{end}}. I get the following output without any of the "-" tags:

```
type {{makeGoTableName .TableName}} struct {
  {{range $key, $value := .TableData}}
    {{makeGoColName $value.ColName}} {{$value.ColType}} `db:"{{makeDBColName $value.ColName}}",json:"{{$value.ColName}}"`
  {{end}}
}
```

Results in:

```
type Dogs struct {

  ID int64 `db:"id",json:"id"`

  DogNumber int64 `db:"dog_number",json:"dog_number"`

}
```

If I add the - tags like so, I can get it close to desirable but it breaks the indentation of the final closing brace:

```
type {{makeGoTableName .TableName}} struct {
  {{range $key, $value := .TableData -}}
    {{makeGoColName $value.ColName}} {{$value.ColType}} `db:"{{makeDBColName $value.ColName}}",json:"{{$value.ColName}}"`
  {{end -}}
}
```

Results in:

```
type Dogs struct {
  ID int64 `db:"id",json:"id"`
  DogNumber int64 `db:"dog_number",json:"dog_number"`
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest [formatting the output from the template](https://godoc.org/go/format#Source) instead of tweaking the template to create Go code in canonical format.  Formatting the template output will get the whitespace right, align the field tags, etc, etc.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126083/is-it-possible-to-use-gofmt-on-templates-that-are-designed-to-be-used-with-go-ge/34126322#34126322) for more info.

Answer (score 24):

Its mostly on playing with the trailing dash, try

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type myGreetings struct {
    Greet []string
}

func main() {
    const txt = `
{
        {{- range $index, $word := .Greet}}
  Hello {{$word -}}!!!
        {{- end}}
}
`
    greetText := myGreetings{
        Greet: []string{"World", "Universe", "Gophers"},
    }
    t := template.Must(template.New("Text").Parse(string(txt)))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, greetText)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eGm3d3IJPp

Output:

```
{
  Hello World!!!
  Hello Universe!!!
  Hello Gophers!!!
}
```