# How to suppress newlines in Go text/template output when filtering ranges with {{if}}

Tags: go-templates

This question is related to [Golang template range newline removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565915/golang-template-range-newline-removal) but is not solved by the answers there.

Given

```
type Data struct {
    Item    string
    IsFruit bool
}

var data = []Data{
    {"banana", true},
    {"apple", true},
    {"onion", false},
    {"peach", true}}

var Template = `
FRUITS ONLY
-----------------
{{range .}}{{if .IsFruit}}{{.Item}}{{else}}{{end}}
{{end -}}
-----------------
`
```

The output from executing `Template` with `data` contains an unwanted newline between `apple` and `peach`.

```
FRUITS ONLY
-----------------
banana
apple

peach
-----------------
```

I've tried many variants of `{{-` and `-}}` without managing to suppress the newline. Eliminating the `{{else}}` also doesn't work.

Please note that pre-filtering the data is not an option for my actual application.

Complete code example at  https://goplay.space/#N_GyaWwjH0Y

Answer (score 5):

The desired output,

```
FRUITS ONLY
-----------------
banana
apple
peach
-----------------
```

can be obtained by changing the template thusly.

```golang
var Template = `
FRUITS ONLY
-----------------
{{range .}}
{{- if .IsFruit}}{{println .Item}}{{end}}
{{- end -}}
-----------------
`
```

The insights needed are:

1. Newlines between closing and ending delimiters are significant, hence `{{-`  is needed to suppress them.
2. The template `println` function **prepends** a newline to its output. That prevents the `{{-`  on the following line from consuming it.

Working solution at https://goplay.space/#I9LzPaAXMr0

IMO, the text/template doc at https://pkg.go.dev/text/template would be improved by adding an explanation of the above.

Comment: This answer meets my needs.  I'll wait a day to accept in case someone posts a better one.

Comment: Is this still the way to go today? Or does a better variant exists now?